# Problem with deleting a new line character

Tags: php

I've tried everything I could think of yet I still couldn't get the code to delete the new line character that is appended at each new entry.

```
if ($_POST['what_to_do']==1){
    if ((isset($_POST['chat_name'])) and ($_POST['chat_name']!=NULL)){
        $chat_name=$_POST['chat_name'];
        $myfile = fopen("users.txt", "a");
        fwrite($myfile, "user_id" . $user_id . " " . "chat_name" . $chat_name . ";\n");
        fclose($myfile);
        $_SESSION['is_chat_logged'] = 1;
    }
}
elseif ($_POST['what_to_do']==2){
    if ($_SESSION['is_chat_logged'] = 1){
            $actual_file=file_get_contents("users.txt");
            $position_start=strpos($actual_file, "user_id" . $user_id . " ");
            $line=file_get_contents("users.txt",FALSE,NULL,$position_start);
            $position_end=strpos($line, ";")+1+$position_start;
            $part_to_be_replaced=substr($actual_file, $position_start, $position_end-strlen($actual_file));
            $new_actual_file= str_replace($part_to_be_replaced, "", $actual_file);
            $myfile = fopen("users.txt", "w");
            fwrite($myfile, $new_actual_file);
            fclose($myfile);
        $_SESSION['is_chat_logged'] = 0;
    }
}
```

---

The users.txt looks like this:

```
user_id1 chat_nameJake;
user_id2 chat_nameSomeone;
user_id43 chat_nameZeke;
user_id22 chat_nameBilly;
```

---

Any help would be appreciated.

---

EDIT: I've found out what the problem was. I was using the substr() function the wrong way. Instead of $position_end-strlen($actual_file) I should have put $position_end-$position_start+1

Answer (score 3):

change

```
fwrite($myfile, "user_id" . $user_id . " " . "chat_name" . $chat_name . ";\n");
```

to

```
fwrite($myfile, "user_id" . $user_id . " " . "chat_name" . $chat_name . ";");
```

The `\n` represents a new line.

Answer (score 2):

notice when you are writing file (fwrite) you are appending a "/n" char which is a new line char. in order to remove new line char you just need to remove that "/n" from your fwrite function